# Another infinite (telescoping?) series question (high school calc)

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{n}{(n+1)!}$$

I don't even know where to begin. I posted another question about a topic like this, but with the factorial thrown into the mix, it is dubious if the same methodology would work.

How do I evaluate this?

Thanks.

Comment: Write out the terms, list them out one by one.

Comment: Indeed telescoping. The $n$-th term is $\frac{n+1-1}{(n+1)!}$, which is $\frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$.

Comment: How did you get to that last conclusion?
EDIT: figured it out. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Add the terms, modified to look like above, and observe the mass cancellations. Added: good!

Comment: Why don't you post that as an answer, @AndréNicolas?

Comment: @hjhjhj57:  Because I am essentially certain the question has been on MSE before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $n/(n+1)!=(n+1-1)/(n+1)!=1/n!-1/(n+1)!$

Then the sum from 0 to infinity is trivially $1$!